# Why TimerTask is running twice?

Tags: java, android, date, timer, timestamp

I want to display a notification at a specific time for my android application. For example: at 3 pm print the notification message. I use this code:

```
private void checkNotificationStatus() {
     timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             addNotificationReminder();
         }
      }, new Date(appointment.getTimeInMillis()));
}

public void addNotificationReminder() {
   System.out.println("i'm here");
}
```

So, the timer works correctly but the message, "I'm here" is displayed twice instead of just once. If I put a `long` instead of a `date` as the second parameter in `TimerTask` (for example 2000), the message is printed just once. Nonetheless, if I put: `appointment.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis()` the message is printed twice again.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Based on the doc, the timer task will execute only once, therefore I suggest using the 'Find Usage' functionality to see whether you accidentally called the method in other places

Comment: On my machine it is only printed once. Maybe put a println() before timer.shedule() to check, whether the method is called multiple times or whether it really is the timers fault.

Comment: where do you call checkNotificationStatus function?

Comment: Ok I think I figured out. I called checkNotificationStatus on fragment's onCreate, so when I open again this fragment, the previous is not destroyed and both call the same function. Thank you all!

Comment: Post and accept an Answer to your own Question, so this will be marked as resolved. Or delete your Question if you believe it has no value to others.

Comment: @NiceWaffel if you post an answer I will accept it as correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The checkNotificationStatus() is probably called two times.
Maybe put a println() before timer.shedule() to check, whether the method is called multiple times or whether it really is the timers fault.